# changing menu color on clicking a new page

Tags: jquery, menu, colors, hyperlink, navigation

I have a very simple navigation bar/menu with few words linking the user to other pages.
My Menu is included in every page from a php library like following:

```
echo <<<_END
<div id="header">
        <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="$doc_root/index.php" title="HOME">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="$doc_root/travel/grid.php" title="My Trips">travelling</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">images</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">travel info</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>                
</div>
_END;
```

My menu.css says:

```
#header{ width:100%; height:40px; background-color: black; border-bottom: 1px silver solid;}
#menu ul {

    list-style: none;
    margin:4px;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu ul li {
    display:inline;
          }

#menu ul li a {
  color: silver;
  font: 20px "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;  
        }
#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li  a.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Question is:
I want that clicking on a menu link, let's say, "travelling" from the home page, the menu background will change color on the "travelling" page.
I guess the jquery function could be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changeMenu();

});
function changeMenu() {
$('???').click(function(){
$('#header').css('background-color' , '#06F');
}
)};
```

Really I don't know how to replace the "???" part with something working.
I tried $('#menu ul li a') and something else...nothing happens. Surely the problem is even something else.
Pls help, thanks.
Morgan

Comment: Because you are switching to the new page when you click on the link, you need some server side code or a session or local storage  to store the selection to get this to work. Pure FE cannot do anything about it as **web  is stateless**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you need to call changeMenu as a function? It will work without.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(){
        $('#header').css('background-color' , '#06F');
    }
});
```

EDIT

Oh, didn't see you were changing pages as well. For the to work, you don't even need JavaScript - it's all handled with HTML and CSS. In brief, you'll giv the HTML page an id and modify the CSS accordingly. For example:

```
<body id="page1">
   [ ... ]
   <div id="header">
       [ ... ]


#header{
    background: #fff;
}
#page1 #header{
    background: #o6f;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I got that but I just wanted to see if I could do it dynamically via Jquery. I'm learning Jq and just wanted to see if it could work somehow. I appreciate your suggestion though.

Comment: The only way it'd work with jQuery is to use ajax and load the new content into the same page (no page refresh needed). I suppose you could also use a session variable, but that seems odd for simple page navigation.